# Twilio Programmable Video - Status callback option on room connect

Tags: javascript, twilio, webhooks, twilio-video

I have Client-side room creation enabled.
Therefore I use connect to create a room, by doing so I came across the need of status callbacks, so I created this code:

```
            connect(token, {
                name: roomname,
                tracks: lt,
                statusCallback: `myOnlineAccessibleUrl`
            });
```

Link is online. Room is created.
This did not solve the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hey, did you fin a solution?

Comment: @AndersonVanzo can't really remember if I did. Maybe make sure you have a publicly accessible url and token is correct.